# Docker-for-desktop kubernetes pull image from private repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-for-mac

I am new to kubernetes and GCP. I am trying to deploy locally. I have an image that it is in a private repository in Google Registry.

I was able to deploy in a GCP cluster, but locally I am getting `ErrImagePull` when I try to apply the deployment.

I tried the following steps

1. Created a `Service Account` with the role `Viewer` and downloaded the json file
2. I encoded the file with the following command `openssl base64 -in file.json -out encodedfile.json`
3. I removed the return characters on the encoded file (to have the encoded content in one line)
4. I created a secret with a yaml to be able to access the docker Registry, and pasted the content of the encoded file on `.dockerconfigjson`

   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Secret
   metadata:
   name: gcr-json-key
   namespace: development
   data:
   .dockerconfigjson: xxxxx
   type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
5. In the deployment I added

   imagePullSecrets:

   - name: gcr-json-key

I am getting the same error, it is not able to pull from the private google registry into my local machine

---

UPDATE 1

I encoded the json file with this command

```
base64 -i myorg-8b8eea93246a.json -o encoded-myorg-8b8eea93246a.json
```

Then I checked that this encoded file works

```
cat encoded-myorg-8b8eea93246a.json | docker login -u _json_key_base64 --password-stdin \
https://us-docker.pkg.dev
```

And it worked

```
Login Succeeded
```

This is the yaml file I am using to create the secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: gcr-json-key
  namespace: development
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: <XXXX content of encoded myorg-8b8eea93246a.json file XXXX>
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

And in the deployment I have

```
...
spec:
  ...
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: gcr-json-key
...
```

The deployment is created but the image is not pulled. In the `kubectl get all` I can see the status `ImagePullBackOff`

When I do a describe to the pod

```
Failed to pull image "gcr.io/xxx/yyy": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials.
```

Comment: 1.What you mean by `I was able to deploy in a GCP cluster, but locally I am getting ErrImagePull when I try to apply the deployment.`? You have gce/gke cluster and everything works fine here, but if you try to download image from your local pc you can't do it?  2.Your deployment is deployed in the same namespace as your secret? Secret API objects reside in a namespace and they can only be referenced only by pods in the same namespace.

Comment: @Jakub thanks for the answer. It is like you wrote, in my cluster in gcp/gke is working. There I use a service account to pull the image from the registry. I applied the serviceAccount and the secret in my local pc context/namespace, but I am getting the same error. Thanks for the comment, it helped me to clarify that secrets also have namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on right path. You need to create secret for registry login. This works for me:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <secret_name> --docker-server=<your.registry.domain.name> --docker-username=<user> --docker-password=<password> --docker-email=<your_email>
```

And then I use this secret for deployment:

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: 
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: server
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <secret_name>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I created the secret, and checked that it is working, but for some reason it seems that the deployment does not have the values. I will update the question. thanks!

Comment: It worked when I created the secret without the yaml, with the command line, and I didn't use the encode base64. I passed the json file right away. thanks!